# TimePicker JS library not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I'm trying to get time picker to work, it's failing, no errors and nothing showing on page.  Inspector shows what is expected.

I wonder if it's because of my imports.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/css/bootstrap.css}" />
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/css/jquery-ui.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/css/timePicker.css}"/>
<script src="/assets/JS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/i18n/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-i18n.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="/assets/JS/timePicker.js"></script>
```

I've then taken a carbon copy from the website instead of targeting my own id.

```
<body>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="basic_example_2" id="basic_example_2" value="" class="hasDatepicker"/>
</div>
```

Script tag at the end of the page:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#theDate" ).datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "/assets/img/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        showButtonPanel: true

    });
    //Time pickers
    $('#basic_example_2').timepicker({

    });


});
```

The date picker is working fine so.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: i would suggest you load the scripts too at the end of the **body** of the page

Comment: @danleyb2 - Thanks, although, it's the same result as before.  The DatePicker is fine but the TimePicker is not.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
//to scroll to current time
$('#basic_example_2').timepicker({'scrollDefault': 'now' });
```

or

```
 //no scroll
 $('#basic_example_2').timepicker();
```

remove the object with no properties

Comment: Having it with no props was my first attempt, although I haven't tried it in combination with the scripts being loaded last...

Just tried and exactly the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue which is pretty strange.  I swapped the ids over so i was targeting my date and voila it worked.  The only difference between them is that one had `value=""` as per the example and my date did not.

Removing the value fixed the problem, maybe thyme leaf doesn't approve?  If anyone can shed any light then that would be great.

hope this helps someone.